# convert short array to audio file?

Tags: android

How can we convert a short array to an audio file.....

```
short[] buffer = {
8130,15752,22389,27625,31134,32695,32210,29711,25354,19410,12253,4329,-3865,-11818,-19032,-25055,-29511,-32121,-327,-31276,-27874,-22728,-16160,-8582,-466};
```

please suggest me the code in which to get a file

```
player=new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(file);
```

in the above code file means the file converted from short array (i.e, buffer...)

Comment: Slap a [WAV header](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) on it and write the result to a file.